# How to differentiate between Blob, Object and String?

Tags: javascript, object

Lets say some function can return **Blob**, **String** or plain **Object**, depending on the use case.
After the value is returned I want to implement different code for each type.
How can I tell them apart?

For simplification I commented the 3 options that can return from the manage function, but this is
the way I manage it right now:

```js
const manage = () => {
    
  return new Blob([JSON.stringify({ myKey: 'myValue'})], { type: 'application/json' });
  
  // return { error: 'my error msg' };
  
  // return 'lets say this is base64 string';
};

const result: Blob | { error: string } | string = manage();

switch(Object.prototype.toString.call(result)) {
    case "[object Blob]":
    console.log('Blob case runs...');
    break;
  case "[object String]":
    console.log('String case runs...');
    break;
  case "[object Object]":
    console.log('Object case runs...');
    break;
  default: console.log('Default case runs...');
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously I am not happy with the **"Object.prototype.toString.call"** solution.
Also some answers suggested to use the **"instance of"** operator, but this is also not a reliable option in my situation.

Can someone point me in a better direction?

Comment: `typeof` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @DiegoDeVita - Won't help at all with `Blob` vs. plain object.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita `typeof new Blob()` returns `"object"`

Comment: *"Also some answers suggested to use the "instance of" operator, but this is also not a reliable option in my situation."* Why not? I'd suggest using separate functions, but a combination of `typeof` and `instanceof` will do the job. `if (typeof x === "string") { /* It's a string */ } else if (x instanceof Blob) { /* It's a blob */ } else { /* It's (presumably) a plain object */ }` (You're right to avoid the `toString` approach, since you may be dealing with a `Blob` subtype.)

Comment: Not sure the best way to do this, but I'd also say that returning different kinds of objects from the same function is very bad practice. Javascript will let you get away with it, but in a more strongly typed language like Java, C++, or C# you wouldn't be able to, for a good reason. When people call a function they should know what the return type is going to be without reading the function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder >Why not?

Because the variable that being evaluated by "instance of" inherits the prototype from his parent and so the operator can return true for the wrong value.

also, quote failed..

Comment: @Viktor - Something that inherits from `Blob` **is** a `Blob`, so why would that be incorrect? If there's some really unusual setup, you'll need to provide an example of it in the question for us to be able to usefully help you with it.

Comment: @Viktor you can work around that by checking for most specific subclasses first, i.e. `if (result instanceof BlobSubclass) { ... }  else if (result instanceof Blob) { ... }`. Your question only states you need to discern between `Blob`, `String` and `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just return the type of data and the data in the `manage` function

```
const manage = () => {
    
  return {
    type: "Bolb",
    data: new Blob([JSON.stringify({ myKey: 'myValue'})], { type: 'application/json' });
  }
   return {type: "error", error: 'my error msg' };
  
   return {type: "string", message: 'lets say this is base64 string'};
};

const result: Object = manage();

switch(result.type) {
    case "Bolb":
    console.log('Blob case runs...');
    break;
  case "string":
    console.log('String case runs...');
    break;
  case "error":
    console.log('Object case runs...');
    break;
  default: console.log('Default case runs...');
 };
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question post, the snippet is an oversimplification, the data in the manage function is returned from an API call and so I don't know which one will it be.